# How a software architect prototype a hybrid complex project

Tags: architecture, software-design, feature-engineering

I have been working in software industry for almost 7 years. I have been doing with several technologies,tools,frameworks and in different programming languages also. But when I have worked in a complex projects,obviously architect by some special software architect, I wonder how he/she made marriages so many third party technologies together and integrated in project also. I would like to know that how he/she manages to prototype this project earlier before to start or you can say I want to know his/her thinking process and what action he/she has taken to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it comes down to experience.  Having lots of experience in many different technologies allows an experienced architect to generally predict where things should work together and where there will be problems.  Software architecture is generally about recognizing patterns of problems, and using solutions that have worked in the past to solve those problems. Much like an experienced software engineer can apply design patterns to solve repeating issues at a code level.

For example, understanding when you have a transaction processing system vs an OLAP vs a messaging system will help an architect to assemble the right components to solve the proposed problems using tools that have been successful in the past.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Conklin. would you please give me some article links that can improve my architect knowledge.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420

Comment: Thanks @Rob for these 2 excellent books suggestion. Appreciated.